# Mapping fields from response in Axios?

Tags: json, typescript, axios, mapping

I have following code:

```
axios.get<Response>(url)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch(error => {
  // handle error
  console.log(error);
});
```

JSON response contains fields that I cannot express in TypeScript:

```
{ 
    "field:Type": "foo"
}
```

like: `name:Type` that contains `string` - in my case it's `"foo"`

How I can map such field in `Response` interface so I could use it later?

```
interface Response {
    myMappedField: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript you have to wrap it with single quotes,

```
interface Response {
  myMappedField?: string;
 'field:Type'?: string;
}
```

In the axios response object you can use the Dot/Bracket notation to read the propery.

```
response.data['field:Type']
```